# Start a service within a TestCase in android

Tags: android, testing, service, servicetestcase

How to start/bind a service from a test case. I tried using the ServiceTestCase it doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

From [`ServiceTestCase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ServiceTestCase.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) documentation:

> When one of your test methods calls `ServiceTestCase.startService()` or `ServiceTestCase.bindService()`, the test case calls `Service.onCreate()` and then calls either `Service.startService(Intent)` or `Service.bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int)`, as appropriate. It also stores values needed to track and support the lifecycle.